# Prove $\{l_x:x\in X\}$ is a basis for $V^*$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V=\mathbb{k}^X$ the vector space over $\mathbb{k}$ of functions of $X\rightarrow \mathbb{k}$. For all $x\in X$ consider the function $l_x:V\rightarrow \mathbb{k}$ defined by $l_x(f) := f(x)$. Prove that $\{l_x:x\in X\}$ is a basis for $V^*$, where $V^*$ is the dual space of $V$,

$$
V^*= End(V,\mathbb{k})$$

I don't have a clear idea of how to solve this, can someone give me a hint for this exercise?

Comment: There must be some condition on $X$. Isn't it a finite set? Hint: what is a basis? Also note that $V^* = \{f| f: V\to K \text{ and } f \text{ linear } \}$

Comment: @Gribouillis $X$ don't have conditions.. can be infinite set. A set is basis of a vector spaces if is linearly independent and generate the space.

Comment: Is X of dimension if yes then use the coordinate projections.

Comment: @GuyFsone i don't understand... can be more explicit? thanks for all

Comment: the coordinate projections take a vector x=(x1....xn )maps to xi for each i

Comment: @Gribouillis iirc without restrictions we could take $X$ to be a $\mathbb{k}$ vector space and therefore $X^{**}$ can potentially be larger than $X$. I don't think it holds for example if we'd take $X$ infinite dimensional.

Comment: This problem is weird because $l_{x}\notin V^{*}$, actually $l_{x}\in V^{**}$.

Comment: If $\dim(V)<\infty$, then you consider a basis $\{e_{1},\ldots,e_{n} \}$, therefore, for each $x\in V$ there exists uniques $\alpha_{1}(x),\ldots,\alpha_{n}(x)$ such that $x=\alpha_{1}(x)e_{1}+\cdots+\alpha_{n}(x)e_{n}$. Then the functios $g_{i}:V\rightarrow \mathbb{k}$ defined by $g_{i}(x)=\alpha_{i}(x)$ are a basis for $V^{*}$.

Comment: If $\dim(V)=\infty$ then everything gets complicated, if  $V$ is a Hilbert space then a procedure similar to the case of finite dimension could be replicated, but if it is not Hilbert we should have more details about the space.

Comment: @DiegoFonseca Well, i suppose $dim(V)$ is finite because this is a exercise of course Algebra II. then i coul consider your basis and follow youy steps, no?

Comment: @Bvss12 If  $\dim(V)$ is finite, then what I said in my second comment is what you need.

Comment: Thanks @DiegoFonseca i will be very grateful

Answer (score 2):

Let $I$ be an index set, then it follows from the universal property of the direct sum that
$$\newcommand{\Hom}{\operatorname{Hom}}\Hom\left(\bigoplus_{i\in I} M_i,k\right)\cong\prod_{i\in I}\Hom(M_i,k).$$

So when all the $M_i=k$, $$\left(k^{\oplus I}\right)^*\cong (k^*)^{I}=k^{I},$$
where $k^{\oplus I}$ is the direct sum of $k$ with itself indexed by $I$, and $k^{I}$ is the product of $k$ with itself $I$ times.

Now in the question you've asked, $V=k^I$, so $V=\left(k^{\oplus I}\right)^*$, and $l_x$ can basically be regarded as a basis for $k^{\oplus I}$, so let
$W=k^{\oplus I}$.
Then essentially for $l_x$ to be a basis for $V^*$, we want to know if the natural map $W\to V^*=W^{**}$ is an isomorphism. The map $W\to W^{**}$ is always injective, and if $X$ is finite, then it's easy to see that $W\to W^{**}$ is surjective as well, since $\dim W=\dim W^*=\dim W^{**}=|X|$, and injective map between vector spaces of the same finite dimension is surjective. However if $X$ is infinite, then we have a linearly independent collection of functions $\delta_x :x\in X$, the functions that take value 1 at x and 0 everywhere else and $1$, the function that is constantly 1. Then we can extend this to a basis for $k^X$, and define an element of the dual space, $\alpha$ by $\alpha(1)=1$ and $\alpha$ is zero for all other elements of the basis. Then $\alpha$ is not in the span of the $l_x$, since $\alpha(\delta_x)=0$ for all $x$, so if $\alpha = \sum a_i l_{x_i}$, we have $\alpha(\delta_{x_i}) = a_i = 0$, but $\alpha\ne 0$. Hence the map $W\to W^{**}$ is not surjective. I.e. $l_x$ do not span $V^*$ if $X$ is infinite.

Answer (score 2):

For simplicity, let $k$ be the two-element field. Then $|k^X|=2^{|X|}$ and so the dimension of $V$ is $2^{|X|}$ by direct computation.

An element of the dual space $V^*$ is basically an indicator function on a basis of $V$, so the cardinality (and dimension) of $V^*$ is $2^{2^{|X|}}>|X|$. Hence $\{l_x:x\in X\}$ cannot be a basis.

If your claim could be proved by only using vector space axioms, it would also be provable when $k$ is the two-element field.

The claim is true when $X$ is finite. Indeed, in this case $\dim V=|X|$ and so also $\dim V^*=|X|$. It's sufficient to prove that $\{l_x:x\in X\}$ is linearly independent. Suppose
$$
\sum_{x\in X}\alpha_xl_x=0
$$
Define, for $y\in X$,
$$
f_y(x)=\begin{cases} 1 & x=y\\ 0 & x\ne y\end{cases}
$$
Then, for every $y$,
$$
0=\sum_{x\in X}\alpha_xl_x(f_y)=\alpha_y
$$

Comment: Thanks egreg! Very clear, one question. I don't see why $\dim V=|X|$ Can you explain me that?

Comment: @Bvss12 Prove that $\{f_y:y\in X\}$ is a basis.

Comment: Thanks @egreg!!! :D

Comment: That system cannot be a basis anyway. but it generates the space

Comment: @GuyFsone That set is linearly independent also when $X$ is infinite; therefore, in the infinite case it cannot be a generating set for $V^*$

Comment: @egreg that set is not . just take the linear forms with respect x and $\lambda x$ . the corresponding linear forms are blatantly depend.

Comment: @GuyFsone I don't understand what you're saying. The argument for linear independence doesn't use finiteness of $X$.

Comment: @egreg   don't we have $l_{\lambda x}= \lambda l_x?$ which obviously gives the dependence

Comment: @GuyFsone And what should $\lambda x$ mean? The set $X$ has no vector space structure and, even if it had, it would be irrelevant for the matter at hand.